# How to run Python3 commands in Android Studio?

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, android-gradle-plugin, android-task

I have a custom gradle task (Exec type) which is responsible for running Python3 command and this task happens before the buildProcess. When i manually fire assembleDebug command via terminal, task works find and there a successful build. But when I manually click Build->Rebuild or Run->Run in Android Studio, there is following message.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:doSomething'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'Python3''
```

Following is my gradle task

```
task doSomething(type:Exec){
    workingDir 'scripts'
    commandLine 'Python3','playGuitar.py'
}

preBuild.dependsOn(doSomething)
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `task doSomething(type:Exec){
    workingDir 'build'
    commandLine 'C:\\Python\\Python27\\python.exe','--help'
}` <= works for me ... *:app:doSomething                                                                     
usage: C:\Python\Python27\python.exe [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg]...* add Python3 to PATH or use full path

Comment: @Selvin This is being used cross-platform, so I want to avoid having absolute paths in the `build.gradle`. How do I add directories to my path in Android Studio? The Path variables screen in preferences doesn't seem to work.